# expect - c program

Tags: c, expect

I am trying to compile a program written in c using the expect.h header.  I am trying this:

```
cc -I/usr/include main.c -lexpect -ltcl
cc -I/usr/include main.c
```

I tried the same with gcc, but to no avail.

I get this:

```
undefined reference to `exp_spawnl'
undefined reference to `exp_expectl'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: I see two different compile commands there.   Are you running both commands? Why?  Which one is generating the errors?

Comment: Are the libexpect.so and libtcl.so iside the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I tried both, actually cc and gcc.  I haven't used gcc for a while to be honest, I'm primarily a Java person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that regardless of what you thought was being used, the expect library being used does not contain those two functions.  So, you need to track down which expect library is actually loaded, and then check whether the functions are in it (they aren't, but you should check to see what is defined).

Once you've found your library, you can use `nm -g libexpect.so` to see the symbols defined.  I would expect that you will not see `exp_spawnl` or `exp_expectl` in the list of defined symbols.

Then you need to find out which version of the library you do have, and decide whether to upgrade, etc.

I am assuming that the names you quote are indeed spelled correctly.

Comment: Interesting, I am on Fedora Core 14 and well the symbolic link is broken for one.  And two, the actual library doesn't have any external symbols ... I thought you could use expect as an API in your own c program.

Comment: @Walter: in principle, you can indeed use `expect`.  You definitely don't need broken links screwing things up.  On my Mac, I ran `otool -L /usr/bin/expect` (equivalent to `ldd` on Linux), and the library appears to be `/System/Library/Tcl/8.5/expect5.44.1.11/libexpect5.44.1.11.dylib`, and running `nm -g` on that shows both `exp_expectl` and `exp_spawnl` symbols.  If you can't find those symbols on your machine in a similar/equivalent library, you need to get that installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the expect header file installed in /usr/include?

I think the undefined reference error comes from the linker and not the compiler. What directory is the library installed to? Try to link against it using the

`-L/path/to/lib -lexpect`

option

Comment: Yes, it is installed there, that is why I specified it on the command line.